# calling REST APIs from batch

Tags: rest, api, microservices, batch-processing

I have a requirement to call a REST API to get some information for a record through a batch job. There will be too many calls for this API as batch job consists of millions of records and calling the REST API for each record through a multi threaded batch does not look right to me as it may overload the web server (although there are multiple instances of web server are there). Is there any design pattern for this kind of use case? Can i call the REST API in chunks such as 1K record at a time? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

*From the information you have provided I can understand that your rest api which is batch based provides a huge info (maybe from a db) and you have millions of requests coming in ....*
For this typical scenario, you need to implement some streaming technology here. Means, something like Apache Kafka (Hazelcast is cost effective alternative). The way you are currently handling it by just having baych jobs and async/threading implementations may help you or may look good on local machines or just test scenarios/environments. If you want to have a proper, stable and robust architecture then you have to go with implementing some streaming technology which will help you to proper channelize the requests and responses for huge volume of data. Else it will be a mess in production. Streaming should be implemented where you are handling bulk data. Here I am not able to pin point exactly where you can have it as I don't know the architecture. *If you need more help then you can post more details like which api's are involved in requests and response , which api is responsible to communicate with user and data source etc.*

Comment: Thanks for responding. I am not sure how KAFKA can solve this issue? Any way for each record , KAFKA consumer also need to call the same API. So either a multi threaded batch job or kafka cluster having multiple consumers, in both the cases there will be many API calls to the endpoint. Regarding some more details about the use case , its like having a DB table with million of records and for each record call an endpoint to check if some of fields of the record are valid or not.

Comment: what you can do is probably you can have a topic between the batch job api and the db data provider api. Create an payload object such that it contains enough info of say 1K requests and then publish it over the topic. Similarly the db api will return with specific answers for that particular requests from the payload object in a response payload object over the topic. Calling directly from one api to other would not seem proper in this case.